# Corona sdk chains example app

Tags: sdk, lua, coronasdk

I am working on a Corona sdk lua app for Android devices that does something similar to the example corona chains app. I would like to make a pivot joint to join two of the chains together at the last link of each chain. Any advice is appreciated.

Jerry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jerry,
I suggest you use LevelHelper (levelhelper.org)
It's a paid application and works only on a mac. It will help you design the physics of the pivot join with the two chains, and it will also generate the code for you in Lua for the Corona SDK.

All you need to do then is, use those generated functions to make it actually work. It makes things very very simple. You could also have a look at the examples on their website.

Here are the video tutorials for joins : http://www.levelhelper.org/?p=1573

I hope this helps .. Cheers..

Comment: Thanks. I finally figured out how to link the chains at the ends. Probably not the best solution though. I'll check out LevelHelper.